# github - how to search for text within a specific folder

Tags: github

In Github, I use the top left search window to search within a repository.

I know the best way is to download the code and search but sometimes I'm unable to do so.

**QUESTION**

How can I limit the search to be within a specific folder?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's what the `path:` option is for, see [Advanced Search](https://github.com/search/advanced).

Example, look for 'searchquery' in mozilla/MozDef but only in the tests/lib directory:

```
searchquery repo:mozilla/MozDef path:/tests/lib
```

Or in URL form that's

```
https://github.com/search?q=searchquery+repo%3Amozilla%2FMozDef+path%3A%2Ftests%2Flib
```